What are the differences between the implementation-defined behavior of LLVM and GCC?
I've noticed that clang documentation doesn't specify how clang behaves in cases specified to be implementation-defined in the relevant standards.
So it's hard to organize the way LLVM's implementation definition differs from GCC's. It's just out of my curiosity.
According to https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/11644
The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type
And
The result of converting a pointer to an integer or -Xarch=v9 vice versa
are two of them.
And what's more?

This is probably much too long to answer in a single question.

If memory serves, in C89 (perhaps just in K&R2) the behavior of converting integer types to shorter N-bit signed types was defined as simply storing the bottom N bits of the result; C99 allowed for the possibility of implementations doing something else, but in practice no C99 implementation has ever been produced for any hardware platform where some other behavior might make more sense, except possibly if that implementation extended the semantics of the language by specifying that integer overflow will be trapped in some particular fashion, in which case it might make sense for it to define the behavior of out-of-range signed integer conversion likewise.  Clang, gcc, and almost every other compiler will, in any "normal" configuration, behave in a manner consistent with C89.
With regard to the conversion between integers and pointers, there has always been a strong convention that implementations targeting platforms which have a "native" relationship between the representations of pointers and integers should handle conversions between them in a manner consistent with that relationship.  Clang, gcc, and almost any other compiler that targets commonplace platforms will behave identically when optimizations are disabled.  When optimizations are enabled, clang versions prior to version 18 would sometimes process computations involving values of type uintptr_t in ways inconsistent with any side-effect-free method of pointer-to-integer conversion, as evidenced by examining the generated code for:
#include <stdint.h>
extern int x[],y[];
int test(int *p)
{
    uintptr_t up = (uintptr_t)p * 33;
    uintptr_t ux = (uintptr_t)(x+1) * 15;        
    y[0] = 1;
    if (up*35 == ux*77)
        *p = 2;
    return y[0];
}

In versions prior to 18, the optimizer would track the "provenance" of up*35 and ux*77 and conclude that *p = 2; couldn't possibly execute if p was equal to y, even though that could happen if x were a single-element array that immediately preceded y in address space.  I'm not sure if version 18 will now reliably treat such conversions as scrubbing provenance information, but at least the values produced seem to behave like numbers.
